# I've an List<Transform> but i cannot access from another class. What can i do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**On RevisedBasicProject4**

```
public class RevisedBasicProject4 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> locationsOfObjects4 = new List<Transform>();

    private void Start()
    {
        Objects4 = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        foreach (var component in Objects4)
        {
            var item = (Transform) component;
            locationsOfObjects4.Add(item); 
        }
        Debug.Log(locationsOfObjects4.Count) //when i debug here,i can see results.
    }


}
```

**On RevisedBasicProject**

```
public class RevisedBasicProject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        RevisedBasicProject4 revisedBasicProject4 = FindObjectOfType<RevisedBasicProject4>();
        Debug.Log(revisedBasicProject4.locationsOfObjects4.Count); 
        //When i debug here i cannot see results
    }
```

Is "FindObjectOfType" wrong way? why i cannot access it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: it's not work. @AmjadSaab

Comment: @AmjadSaab don't make everything static just to access it easy / lazy .. this usually causes more issue than it solves

Comment: Your issue is most probably execution order .. convert the first `Start` to `Awake` to be sure it is definitely executed first

Comment: Yes! It's solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most probably execution order / race condition.

It is not guaranteed that `RevisedBasicProject4.Start` is executed **before** `RevisedBasicProject.Start`.

Convert the first `Start` to `Awake` to be sure it is definitely executed first.

My personal general thumb rule on this:

- Use [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) to initialize everything where you do not rely on others (e.g. for `GetComponent` calls, initialize fields etc)
- Use [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) where you do rely on others (like accessing fields of other components)

This solves most of order based issues.

Where this isn't enough you can still play with the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) or use a more complex event system.

---

In general instead of `FindObjectOfType` if it is an option I would always prefer

```
[SerializeField] private RevisedBasicProject4  RevisedBasicProject4;
```

and drag in the according object into this slot in the Inspector within Unity.